# Count files downloads per user and write it in txt file using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to count the downloads of files. Once the client click a link write in a txt file the username and path and number of counts.

my problem is: How can I make it to group same users and what they clicked under each other because now I am getting this with no order:

Username: Lee | Number of download: 50 | File Downloaded:/our-products/88-series-led-wall-light

Username: Nour | Number of download: 50 | File Downloaded:/our-products/88-series-led-wall-light

Username: Lee | Number of download: 50 | File Downloaded:/our-products/88-series-led-wall-light

Username: X | Number of download: 50 | File Downloaded:/our-products/88-series-led-wall-light

Username: Lee | Number of download: 50 | File Downloaded:/our-products/88-series-led-wall-light

```
if( isset($_GET['count'])){
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $_SESSION['count'] = $_SESSION['count']+1;


    if(file_exists('countClick_images.txt')){
        $myFile = fopen('countClick_images.txt', 'w') or die('unable to open file');
        $txt = 'Username: ' .$username.' | Number of download: '.$_SESSION['count'].' | File Downloaded:'.$path ;
        fwrite($myFile,"\n". $txt);
        fclose($myFile);
    }else {
        $myfile = fopen("countClick_images.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $txt = 'Username: ' .$username.' | Number of download: '.$_SESSION['count'].' | File Downloaded:'.$path ;
        fwrite($myfile, "\n". $txt);
        fclose($myfile);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use mysql table to store your count info..

Comment: I dont have access to database and the client requested a txt file

Comment: Possibly use XML rather than a text file if you do not want to take a Database approach. You could automate the XML by adding every user to the sheet with a default value of 0. Each download will simply query the username and increment the field. You can easily explain the advantages to the client (maintenance) and they will probably go with it.

Comment: You can use one of many 'Flat file' storage libraries for PHP rather than write your own

Comment: If for example you simply used, `serialize()` function for PHP to store a large array to the text file and `unserialize()` when reading it back to a PHP array. This wouldn't work well for a large data-set as the file would become quite large and slow.

Comment: I will try your idea @pokeybit Thanks

Comment: As an alternative: instead of saving the total count, just append the path and username to the file. I suggest a csv format, e.g. Wushu06;/our-products/88-series-led-wall-light. Then you can easily iterate the file and do aggregations as you see fit. The file will be larger, but it allows for more flexible calculations.

Comment: maybe a bad idea (if you have thousands of distinct users): what about one file per username?

Comment: @jeff an event log like this is neither uncommon, nor should the file size become problematic. Let's say an average line is 50 ascii chars. Let's also say you got 10000 users and each one downloaded 500 files. So you got 5.000.000 lines times 50 byte. That's not even 2.5 MB then. I'd worry about splitting up by username (or maybe dates) when that really becomes an issue.

Comment: I have more than 2000 users and 1000 product so ...

Answer (score 0):

**Single file version**

Having in mind some suggestions in comments I would do something like this.

You can store the information serialized in the file, so you can restore it easily to a php variable.

I wouldn't store "count" because it's a redundant information if you have the list of downloaded items. You can count that array always you want.

First I run this script to initialize the file with the data you gave.

```
<?php
// Only first time to load initial data in file
$data = [
    'Lee' => [
        'files' => [
            '/our-products/88-series-led-wall-light',
            '/our-products/88-series-led-wall-light',
            '/our-products/88-series-led-wall-light'
        ]
    ],
    'Nour' => [
        'files' => [
            '/our-products/88-series-led-wall-light'
        ]
    ],
    'X' => [
        'files' => [
            '/our-products/88-series-led-wall-light'
        ]
    ]
];

$file = 'countClick_images.txt';
file_put_contents($file, serialize($data));
```

This generates a file with this serialized data:

```
a:4:{s:3:"Lee";a:1:{s:5:"files";a:3:{i:0;s:38:"/our-products/88-series-led-wall-light";i:1;s:38:"/our-products/88-series-led-wall-light";i:2;s:38:"/our-products/88-series-led-wall-light";}}s:4:"Nour";a:1:{s:5:"files";a:1:{i:0;s:38:"/our-products/88-series-led-wall-light";}}s:1:"X";a:1:{s:5:"files";a:1:{i:0;s:38:"/our-products/88-series-led-wall-light";}}s:8:"testUser";a:1:{s:5:"files";a:1:{i:0;s:10:"/test/file";}}}
```

After that, I modified your script to use `serialize()` and `unserialize()`.

```
$storeFile = 'countClick_images.txt';

// I forced some GET data here to try
$_GET['username'] = 'testUser';
$_GET['path'] = '/test/file';

if (isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['path'])) {

    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $downloadedFile = $_GET['path'];

    if (file_exists($storeFile)) {
        $data = unserialize(file_get_contents($storeFile));
    } else {
        $data = [];
    }

    echo "Data before:\n" . print_r($data,1);

    // This creates a particular user data structure
    // I put the files array into a 'files' key for you to be able to store more information of that user

    if (!isset($data[$username])) {
        $data[$username] = ['files' => []];
    }

    $data[$username]['files'][] = $downloadedFile;

    echo "Data after:\n" . print_r($data,1);

    // This creates the file if it doesn't exist
    file_put_contents($storeFile, serialize($data));
}
```

Also, I think it would be a good idea to store all the information in one file per user in order to avoid the use of a huge file if you have many users and downloads.

Comment: Thanks! Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Multi file version** (Also using user id instead of user names as index)

I made a second version of how I would really do this, in order to avoid to potential issues: huge single file and bad usernames.

This script generates three different files with the initial data you gave, one file per user.

```
<?php
// Only first time to load initial data in file
$data = [
    '1' => [
        'username' => 'Lee',
        'files' => [
            '/our-products/88-series-led-wall-light',
            '/our-products/88-series-led-wall-light',
            '/our-products/88-series-led-wall-light'
        ]
    ],
    '2' => [
        'username' => 'Nour',
        'files' => [
            '/our-products/88-series-led-wall-light'
        ]
    ],
    '3' => [
        'username' => 'X',
        'files' => [
            '/our-products/88-series-led-wall-light'
        ]
    ]
];

foreach ($data as $userId => $userData) {
    $fileName = 'countClick_images_user_' . $userId . '.txt';
    file_put_contents($fileName, serialize($userData));
}
```

Now you have these files:

```
countClick_images_user_1.txt
countClick_images_user_2.txt
countClick_images_user_3.txt
```

After that, the script to add new downloads would look like this:

```
<?php

$_GET['userid'] = '4';
$_GET['path'] = '/test/file';
$_GET['username'] = 'testUser'; // You need this input name only first time a user downloads something

if (isset($_GET['userid']) && isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['path'])) {

    // You can add more controls here to validate input data
    $userId = $_GET['userid'];
    $userName = $_GET['username'];
    $downloadedFile = $_GET['path'];

    $storeFile = 'countClick_images_user_' . $userId . '.txt';

    if (file_exists($storeFile)) {
        $data = unserialize(file_get_contents($storeFile));
    } else {
        $data = [];
    }

    echo "Data before:\n" . print_r($data,1);

    // Here you create data structure
    if (!isset($data['username'])) {
        $data['username'] = $userName;
        $data['files'] = [];
    }

    $data['files'][] = $downloadedFile;

    echo "Data after:\n" . print_r($data,1);

    file_put_contents($storeFile, serialize($data));
}
```

First time you run it, it creates a new file for user 4, creates the data structure, add its first download and stores it into the file.

If you run it again, it takes the data of user's 4 file, add the new download and stores it again in the file.

**Output all users info:**

```
<?php

// Format:
// * username: nour | clicks: 55 | files: file1, file2, file3 * lee | clicks 5| files: file1, file3 * x | clicks 22| files: file3

// glob returns an array with all file names that match that pattern
foreach (glob("countClick_images_user_*.txt") as $storeFile) {

    $userData = unserialize(file_get_contents($storeFile));

    echo "username: " . $userData['username'] . " | ";
    echo "clicks: " . count($userData['files']) . " | ";
    echo "files: " . implode(",", $userData['files']);
    echo "\n";
}
```

This will output this:

```
username: Lee | clicks: 3 | files: /our-products/88-series-led-wall-light, /our-products/88-series-led-wall-light, /our-products/88-series-led-wall-light
username: Nour | clicks: 1 | files: /our-products/88-series-led-wall-light
username: X | clicks: 1 | files: /our-products/88-series-led-wall-light
username: testUser | clicks: 2 | files: /test/file, /test/file
```

Comment: I am looking for a result like this :
* username: nour | clicks: 55 | files:  file1, file2, file3
* lee | clicks 5| files:  file1,  file3 
* x | clicks 22| files:  file3

Comment: Easy! Now you have all your data in php variables so you can output it the way you want. I edited the answer to add a script that reads all the files and outputs all the data the way you asked to.